# How can I solve UnboundLocalError out of the function?

Tags: python

I got a popular error in python like [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

```
x = 10
def foo():
    x += 1
    print(x)
foo()
```

If it runs, we got this error like the followings

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

But in my case, the function is not the one I made but It's included in the library. In this case, how can I solve this problem without declaring the variable with global keyword in the function? I think it is not good idea to modify the function in the library.

Comment: If that function is in a library, the library is broken.  There's no way such a function can work.

Comment: You should contact the maintainer of this library

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not control the function, it would be better to rename your variable. May be name it something different?

And yes.

- Using global inside the function scope is bad.
- Since you didn't create the library, you probably can't modify it **easily** (the next update would rewrite your changes).
- Even if you can modify it, using `global` would be bad

Comment: The variable is declared in the function so that I can't rename it neither.

Comment: The variable outside the function. You can rename that one, no?

Comment: @mansun No, I can't rename the variable and the problem is that it needs to be initialized before it is assigned. Replacing the variable name can not be a solution..

Comment: You can not change the function, you can not rename the variable, you can't make it global - In that case I am out of solutions :(

Comment: ok. I think I have to give up using the library. Because, the place where the function is called is also in the library so that I can't declare a global keyword, neither